# C++ Linked List isEmpty Function

Tags: c++, linked-list, is-empty

I want to check, whether a linked list in C++ is empty or not. I have following class:

```
class IntLinkedList
{
    private:
        struct LinkedListNode        // Structure for linked list
        {
            int value;
            struct LinkedListNode *next;
        };
        LinkedListNode *head;       // List head pointer

    public:
        IntLinkedList(void)         // Constructor
        { head = NULL; }

        ~IntLinkedList(void);       // Destructor
        void AppendNode(int);
        void InsertNode(int);
        void DeleteNode(int);
        void DisplayList(void);
        bool isEmpty(LinkedListNode*);
};  

// isEmpty function
bool IntLinkedList::isEmpty(LinkedListNode *node)
{
    bool status;
    node = head;
    if ( node->next == NULL )
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;  
}
```

But I can't use this function in other class via an object of the same class.

How can I check the empty list using a **function** that would be accessible in another class through the object of the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is caused by the fact that you declared your function as `bool isEmpty(LinkedListNode)` but you are trying to define it as `bool isEmpty(LinkedListNode*)`. The difference is that in the definition you have a pointer, while in the declaration there is just an object. You have to pick one, as these are completely different things.

That said, I don't see why you need the argument at all to check whether your list is empty. Just drop the argument altogether and use `if ( head->next == NULL )` - non-static member functions are always called through an instance of the class.

Just for completeness, first item in your list is pointed to by `head`, so in order to check if there is anything in the list, you should check if it is a null pointer:

```
bool IntLinkedList::isEmpty() const
{   //added const for const-correctness, should be added to declaration as well
    return head == nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got that error but still, I can't use this function in some other class through object because I can't provide a parameter of type `LinkedListNode`. The problem is still there i.e., how to define a function to check the list is empty or not.

Comment: As I said, drop the argument and define it as `bool isEmpty()`. You will be calling it like `IntLinkedList ll; ll.isEmpty();`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @codekaizer it will obviously be an error, but it's not in the scope for this question to write a correct implementation, but show the correct line of thought for implementing member functions (and indicate that pointers are different than instances, but I guess that could have been a typo)

Comment: ok @codekaizer, you might be right that there is no harm in being thorough - I have edited in the implementation that OP would eventually think of himself

Answer (score 0):

Following [`list.empty()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/empty/),

> Returns whether the list container is empty (i.e. whether its size is
>   0).

Two suggestions:

Have a `size` variable that checks for the number of nodes in your list, this way your `isEmpty()` is just `return size == 0;`

Or in your current implementation, just modify to:

```
bool isEmpty() {
   return head == null; // if head is null, there's no node in list
}
```